# Form submit (POST) to php page gives blank page unless I refresh

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I have a simple login page with 2 textfields and a button. When I press "Submit", the URL changes to the php page but I see absolutely nothing at all. I have no idea how to fix it so I'm hoping somebody can help me.

My HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/customtheme.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a class="ui-btn-left" href="index.html" data-icon="back">Back</a>
                <h1><span>Login</span></h1>
                <a class="ui-btn-right" href="#" data-icon="info">i & &euro;</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-position="relative">
                <div class="loginform">
                    <form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="POST">
                        <span>Email adress:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
                        <span>Password:</span>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></input>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my login.php:

```
<?php session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',TRUE); 
    echo ("Test");
?>
```

I don't even see 'Test' nor any error...

Comment: put an echo before the `session_start()`. if you don't even see that, then something's killing your script before it can ever reach the rest of the code. the ini_set/reporting changes should be made at the php.ini level, so they're in effect when the script tries to start up. it's pointless to try to change them after startup, if it's a startup error killing things.

Comment: @MarcB is on to something... Make sure you set [`error_log`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) in php.ini so you can get fatal startup errors (and others) at least somwhere.

Comment: try echoing "test after you remove the 3 lines before echo and add each line one by one and see which one is causing the problem. if it still does not work that means something else is causing the script not tu run at all.

Comment: I tested your code and it has something to do with your jQuery in your `<head></head>` because when I removed all that, it echo'ed `test`

Comment: I placed and echo before the session_start and I don't even see that...

Comment: Possible solution: Add what you have in your `<head></head>` inside your `login.php` and it will work. TESTED @Joetjah

Comment: @Fred-ii- I feel like a total noob right now. But how exactly do you mean?

Comment: Never mind, that's basically what I was going to suggest with the answer below. @Joetjah

Comment: Add attribute `data-ajax="false"` to form, disabling ajax completely will eliminate many features in JQM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually not a php problem. Assume you are using JQuery mobile. Disabling `data-ajax` may help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

Use this code on your html page.

Comment: Before <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: I tested this in both the head and body, and it didn't work. @Joetjah [see my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107541/form-submit-post-to-php-page-gives-blank-page-unless-i-refresh#comment29962198_20107541)

Comment: Saw your codepad file just now, very well done :) +1 @Md.Al-Amin

Comment: @Fred-ii- You too thank you a lot for your time and effort! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, glad a solution was found and that's the important thing, cheers. @Joetjah

Comment: Add attribute `data-ajax="false"` to form, disabling ajax completely will eliminate many features in JQM.